# Form action is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this html code:

```
<form action="connect.php" method="get" name="registerForm">
            <h3>Not a member yet? Sign Up!</h3>
            <p>Username:</p><input type="text" name="name" id="registerinput_username">
                <div id="usernamereq2"><p>Field is required.</p><img src="ximg.png" alt="x"></div>
            <p>Email:</p><input type="text" name="email" id="registerinput_email">
                <div id="emailreq"><p>Field is required.</p><img src="ximg.png" alt="x"></div>
            <p>A password will be e-mailed to you.</p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" id="registersubmit">
</form>
```

and then i run a php function to post the inputs in my database:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","photoalbum");

$username=$_GET['name'];
$email=$_GET['email'];

$sql="INSERT INTO registration (UserName, Email)
VALUES ('$username', '$email')";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

However, since I am also running a javascript function at the same time to check if the inputs were valid, the connect.php does not run.

here is the javascript:

```
function validateFormRegister()
    {
        var email=document.forms["registerForm"]["email"].value;
        var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
        var name=document.forms["registerForm"]["name"].value;
        var x=name.length;
            if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length)
                {
                    alert("Email is invalid.");
                }
            if(x<5){
                    alert("Username is too short! Must be at least 5 characters.");
                }
            if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length && x<5)
            {
            return false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Where is mysqli_query in your connect.php??

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: BTW: Your query is vulnerable to SQL-injection

Comment: You're not calling your `validateFormRegister()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the form's `action` parameter to your PHP script, and do any JavaScript processing in a JavaScript event `onsubmit`:

```
<form action="connect.php" method="get" name="registerForm" 
onsubmit="return validateFormRegister()">
```

When the form is submitted, it will trigger the JavaScript function, which will then validate the input fields and return a boolean result (true or false). The form submission takes place only if the return value is true, in which case the values are sent to the PHP script (`connect.php`) for further processing.

Also note that your query is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). I suggest you learn about [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and use that in your code so your code is safe from SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score -1):

change these into (you are missing $result = $con->query($sql) )

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","photoalbum");    
$username=$_GET['name'];
$email=$_GET['email'];
$sql="INSERT INTO registration (UserName, Email)
VALUES ('$username', '$email')";
$result = $con->query($sql);
mysqli_close($con);
?>

function validateFormRegister()
    {
        var email=document.forms["registerForm"]["email"].value;
        var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
        var name=document.forms["registerForm"]["name"].value;
        var x=name.length;
            if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length)
                {
                    alert("Email is invalid.");
                }
            if(x<5){
                    alert("Username is too short! Must be at least 5 characters.");
                }
            if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length && x<5)
            {
            return false;
            }
    return true;
    }

<form action="connect.php" method="get" name="registerForm" onsubmit="return validateFormRegister()">
```